# how to change color of icon of bootstrap icon?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I change the color of glyphicon? The current color is showing in black, I want to change it to white.
I have tried to do it as :

```css
.glyphicon {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button class="nav-bar1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span><p>Dashboard</p></button>
```

Also, I have cleaned my browser history but still it doesn't work, I am using Bootstrap-3.3.7. [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiQIH.png) to see my html in browser.

Comment: your code should work in fact. I just made a codepen and it worked. Im pretty sure you have some css overiding you style. Try to add the `important` to the css

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I have tried it also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also target the `::before` component which is where the content is, like this:

```
.glyphicon::before {
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `!important` after color to override it

Add :

```
.white-icon{
color:white !important;
}
```

```css
.white-icon{
color:white !important;
}
```

```html
<button class="nav-bar1"><span class="glyphicon white-icon glyphicon-cog"></span><p>Dashboard</p></button>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: My question is for change the color of an icon which is not appearing in the snippet, can you please click on given link (Click here) and check my code in this image?

Comment: Why add white color to nav-bar1 ?

Comment: @purvi add white-icon css class and i have edited the answer for the code
`.white-icon{
color:white !important;
}`

Comment: because icon dosen't appearing before the text, it is appearing when I hover on that button

Comment: Did you add the above class ? are you still facing the same issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You can either add this directly to the style:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" style="color:blue!important"></span>
```

Or you can add it as a class to your icon and then set the style color to it in CSS

HTML

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog blue"></span>
```

CSS

```
.blue {
    color: blue!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button class="nav-bar1"><span style="color:blue!important" class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span><p>Dashboard</p></button>
```

Comment: Yes...I have tried the same but still it dosen't working

Comment: style="color:blue!important".I checked it is working in https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_glyph_cog&stacked=h

Comment: I have added working code snippet also.Hope this will help for users further

Answer (score 0):

```
<button class="nav-bar1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" style="color: white;"></span><p>Dashboard</p></button>
```

The example above uses inline styling. The example below is what you should add into your stylesheet if you prefer that way.

```
.glyphicon glyphicon-cog{
    color:white;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.nav-bar1 .glyphicon{
   color:blue !important;
 }
```

That should do it.